# string Does not contain definition for Where, C# in SSIS Package

Tags: c#, ssis

string Does not contain definition for Where, C# in SSIS Package, what is missing please?

```
string ToASCII(string subjectString)
{
    var newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    newStringBuilder.Append(subjectString.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)
                                         .Where(x => x < 128)
                                         .ToArray());
    return newStringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Where` method of the `string` class, is an extension method and you must provide it's namespace. So you should add this namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what's wrong with:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(subjectString.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD));
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: *Not really an answer, but this wouldn't have fit well in the comment space, and it may be the OP will decide to use this code.